# Como fazer um update em diversas linhas de uma tabela com codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bootstrap

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte problema, eu tenho uma tabela de estoque. segue img:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esses produtos do estoque estão agrupados toda vez que eu dou uma entrada ele soma com o que já existe e cria uma nova linha no banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a questão é não consigo fazer um update que seria a baixa do estoque retirando os produtos que tem o mesmo código linha por linha independente da quantidade, a questão é não é que seja impossível, é que realmente eu não sei nem por onde começar, podem me ajudar. preciso que se faça um update que vasculhe as linhas e verifique a quantidade para fazer a retirada do total exigido e que não seja possível que se faça uma retirada maior que a quantidade das linhas que possuem o mesmo código de produto somadas.

OBRIGADO!

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Depois, edite sua pergunta e insira o seu código.

Comment: Está criando a tabela com `CI_Table`? Usa `JQuery`? Cadê o `model`? o `controller`? a `view`?

Comment: Mesmo código ? qual código, especifica o nome da coluna. e o que seria dar baixa ? deletar os produtos ?